# Is SELECT DISTINCT always redundant when using a GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, distinct

Is there a case where adding DISTINCT would change the results of a SELECT query that uses a GROUP BY clause?

[Group by and distinct produce similar execution plans.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/29/sql-server-difference-between-distinct-and-group-by-distinct-vs-group-by/)

From my understanding, tables that use a GROUP BY clause can only have columns from the GROUP BY or aggregate functions.

[List of aggregate functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) appears to be deterministic and combinations from the GROUP BY would be unique so my assumption is that it would be redundant.

**EDIT 1:** Adding the DISTINCT keyword directly after SELECT. Not anywhere in the query like @lad2025's example: SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT col) ... GROUP BY name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are under no obligation to `SELECT` all the `GROUP BY` columns so in this case it would change the results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sys.objects
GROUP BY schema_id, name
```

--- or

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)
FROM sys.objects
GROUP BY schema_id, name
```

Answer (score 1):

The groups, as defined by the expressions and columns that appear in the `group by` clause, will be unique in the result set. As long as all those same columns are included in the `select` list then `distinct` will be redundant. As noted by Martin Smith this is not required though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can change result when you use `DISTINCT` with aggregation function:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(col) AS result
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

vs

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT col) AS result
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

In other cases like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

`DISTINCT` is almost always redundant.

**EDIT:**

Corner case (when `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` column list does not match):

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col1 INT, col2 INT);

INSERT INTO #tab
VALUES (1,1), (1,1), (2,1), (2,2)

SELECT DISTINCT col2
FROM #tab
GROUP BY col1, col2

SELECT col2
FROM #tab
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/408689)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╗                 ╔══════╗
║ col2 ║                 ║ col2 ║
╠══════╣      vs         ╠══════╣    
║    1 ║                 ║    1 ║           
║    2 ║                 ║    1 ║           
╚══════╝                 ║    2 ║
                         ╚══════╝
```